# SharePoint 2016 - Sorry, we couldn't open 'http://.......doc' error when opening a file on a Sharepoint Site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I have sharepoint 2016 installed, everything was working just fine, but suddenly i got the following error:

Sorry, we couldn't open http://.....doc file.

After investigating, i found that the Sharepoint Search Host Controller Service is stopped, i was trying to start it, but it won't start.

it gives the following error when trying to start such service:

```
**Windows Could not start the Sharepoint Search Host Controller service on Local Computer
Error 2: The system cannot find the file specified.**
```

I have done several solutions found on the internet such as starting the service from the sharepoint central admin or by restarting services, but nothing worked.

i was also trying to change the user for the sharepoint search host controller service, it won't allow me, it gives the following error:

```
**An object of the type Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWindowsServiceCredentialDeploymentJobDefinition named "windows-service-credentials-SPSearchHostController" already exists under the parent Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchRuntimeService named "SPSearchHostController".  Rename your object or delete the existing object**
```

i deleted the timer job of windows-service-credentials and i was able to reassign the service account, but then the timer job windows-service-credentials was created automatically and i wasn't able to start the service.

Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sometime I've used [this solution](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/125854/windows-could-not-start-the-sharepoint-search-host-controller) to resolve the same issue for SharePoint 2013

Comment: @MatiurRahman i have checked the link, but i have no such path, where can i find such nodes?

Comment: Path C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0 is for SharePoint 2013, and for SharePoint 2016, it might be C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\16..\.. How many servers are in your farm?

Comment: @MatiurRahman i have 1 server in my farm, but i have no such path either, wierd

Comment: So, it may not be applicable to your scenario. The Node.ini file is to keep all nodes in the farm in sync.

Comment: @MatiurRahman can you please check the comment i wrote on the answer given, maybe you can help too please, thanks!

Comment: Hi Ahmad - I'm seeing that path **C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\Data\Office Server\Applications\Search\Nodes** does exist for a 1-Server SP 2013 farm. So, you've a few options: 1) Can you check in the drive where SP 2016 has been installed? 2) Check the registry under key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office Server\.. under that you should see 15.0 or 16.0 and then "Search" key. That should show where Search being installed at

Comment: Also, as you might already know, you can have more than one **Search Service** (SSA) application in a SP Farm (We've in SP 2013). You can provision a brand new SSA and configure the content source and crawl it again. Let me know if you need help on provisioning a new SSA with Power Shell script (used in SP2013)

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps to troubleshoot the issue:

1.Open Registry Editor as an administrator .

2.Navigation to "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SPSearchHostController\ImagePath".

3.Right click -> Modify -> Set value data as "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\16.0\Search\HostController\hostcontrollerservice.exe".

4.Try to start SharePoint Search Host Controller service again.

Comment: I have founded that the search host controller service is not found on the C drive, i think it was installed on a lun from a nas storage, the NAS had some issues 3 months ago and the LUN was deleted. But the wierd thing is that the sharepoint was working all the 3 months just all fine even after the NAS issue, how was it working normally while there is no path for search host controller, we just a week ago we got the issue that we can't start the service because the path is not found anymore?
and how can i solve this?

Comment: where i can get such service without reinstalling the sharepoint 2016 again, Thanks!